# How to integrate openinviter code in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, wif, import-contacts

I am developing a Social Networking Site using **Asp.Net and C#**.There is an option for All users to import their contact from deferent mails eg:- **gmail,Hotmail,yahoo,reddiffmail etc**...
I found some source code in **openinviter.com**.But that is Coded in PHP.
How i use that files in my Asp.net site?
pls help me with some sample code...

http://openinviter.com/demo/

How to integrate it?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for claim based authentication. WIF will enables you to do authentication with external security providers:

[Windows Identity Foundation Simplifies User Access for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351)

[claims based authentication using windows identity foundation](http://blog.discountasp.net/claims-based-authentication-using-windows-identity-foundation/)

Answer (score 0):

I've used openinviter before from an ASP.Net site and it worked reasonably well - although plugins like facebook did break from time to time - mainly because the openinviter code largely works through HTML-scraping techniques.

To integrate this code within ASP.Net, I hosted the PHP application within a separate web app (in my case on a separate subdomain) and then showed that app within an iframe on my main site.

To do what you are asking - to import details into ASP.Net - you could modify the openinviter PHP so that instead of showing friend names it performs some sort of postback to your ASP.Net site. This will enable you to continue benefiting from new and improved openinviter PHP plugins as they are released. The code you would need to modify is pretty easy to find - take a look in `default.php` near to the code `foreach ($contacts as $email=>$name)` - this is where the list of contacts is most easily available. (If you want to intercept after selection take a look instead for `foreach ($selected_contacts as $email=>$name)`

However, one word of warning - please note that for many of the plugins (e.g. facebook) won't allow you access to the private details so you can't "import" the contacts directly - instead these plugins allow you to send messages (e.g. facebook mails) to those contacts.